# Convergence in probability to a contant implication

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in probability to $c$. Does it follow that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n<c)=0?
$$
Using the definition, I know that for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n<c-\epsilon)=0.
$$
Can I take the limit w.r.t. $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X_n=c-\frac 1 n$. Then $X_n \to c$ in probability (in fact almost surely) but $P\{X_n<c\}=1$ for all $n$.